# How can I repair my system if I forgot to remove the Gimp registry plugin when using Gimp 2.8?

Tags: gimp

I've installed gimp 2.8 on ubuntu 12.04 forgetting to remove gimp registry plug-in and now I can not open gimp, remove it, repair it and the ubuntu software centre doesn't work anymore saying me I've to repair the dameged packages, but when I try to do it it doesn't work!!!
How can I solve my problem?
thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly remove the Gimp 2.8 repository by running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
```

and then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now remove the plugin-registry as it is not supported on 2.8:

```
sudo apt-get remove gimp-plugin-registry
```

Once that's done you can install Gimp 2.8:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Answer (score 1):

also, after upgrading to 12.04, make sure to go back into synaptic and check the boxes on the first tab of the repositories window.  They seem to revert back to being unchecked when I upgraded over the internet.  Once rechecked, the install goes smoothly.