# New problem-on-12-04-with-gimp-2-8

Tags: gimp

I have the same problem stated here [How can I repair my system if I forgot to remove the Gimp registry plugin when using Gimp 2.8?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132114/problem-on-12-04-with-gimp-2-8) but it is impossible to install ppa-purge, because of the fact that ubuntu software centre doesn't work anymore saying me I've to repair the dameged packages, but when I try to do it it doesn't work...like for Leonardo....
How can i do to repair the ubuntu software centre and repair Gimp?
Thanks.

Comment: try sudo apt-get autoremove

Comment: I tyed without and then with the -f option, here the output

`(....)
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare /var/cache/apt/archives/gimp_2.8.0-1ubuntu0ppa4~precise_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 tentata sovrascrittura di "/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/file-xmc" presente anche nel pacchetto gimp-plugin-registry 3.5.4-1
(...)
   dpkg-deb: errore: il sottoprocesso paste è stato terminato dal segnale (Pipe interrotta)
...
Si sono verificati degli errori nell'elaborazione:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gimp_2.8.0-1ubuntu0ppa4~precise_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay..

**Here is a method that should *NOT* be tried unless nothing else works...**

At first wait and see if you get any other answer here...only if you dont,use this method..

In this method,we are going to delete the status entry of GIMP 2.8(Thus bypassing  dpkg)

> > **NOTE:***The status file is an utterly importatnt file.In the steps given below,first we will be making a backup of the original file b4 editing for safety so that if anything goes wrong,your status file can be recovered*.

Enter these commands in the terminal-

> `sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.orig`

now enter the following command to open the status file as a superuser in gedit

> `gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status`

In the file search for a block that will start with something like this:(you may use <kbd>CLTR+F</kbd> to find it.just put **gimp** in that search box.)

```
Package: gimp

Status:

....

....

....

Original-Maintainer: Ari Pollak <ari@debian.org>
```

After you find it,select that complete block(**Not even a single space or line more than that**) and delete it.

Save the file and close it.

Then go in software sources and remove the repository.

You have successfully removed Gimp.

you can confirm it by typing in the terminal

> `sudo apt-get remove gimp`

You should get an error saying ***Package not found*** or ***No such package installed***

**NOTE1:***FOLLOW ONLY THE GIVEN INSTRUCTIONS.NOTHING EXTRA IF YOU DO NOT WANT TO SCREW UP SOMETHING ELSE.DELETING EVEN ONE LINE EXTRA IN THE STATUS FILE WILL BREAK IT AND WILL  NOT LET YOU UPDATE ANYTHING AFTER THAT(Though we have created a backup file its best to take care)*

**NOTE2:***WHEN YOU OPEN THE STATUS FILE IN GEDIT,ALONG WITH IT YOU WILL FIND ANOTHER FILE OPENING UP IN THE BACKGROUND* `Untitled Document`*IGNORE IT.YOU MAY JUST CLOSE IT*